# Limiting the size of a dict in a one-liner

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array of dictionaries or a dictionary itself and I'd like to limit it to a length of 1000. Here is what I have so far:

```
MAX_ROWS = 1000
data[:MAX_ROWS] if isinstance(data, list) else ...
```

Normally I'd do this with a forloop such as:

```
d = {}
for key in list(data.keys())[:MAX_ROWS]:
    d[key] = data[key]
```

is there a way to do this in the above one-liner?

Comment: FYR: unless you use Python >= 3.6, `list(data.keys())` evaluates to a somewhat random list of keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {key: data[key] for key in list(data)[:MAX_ROWS]}
```

Also note that `list(data)` will return the keys of `data`.

Here's another possibly more efficient solution (untested):

```
from itertools import islice
d = {key: data[key] for key in islice(data, MAX_ROWS)}
```